# PHP - How to SCP local file from BASH OSX to remote via SSH with Password in PHP?

Tags: php, bash, macos, ssh

I want PHP to send myfile.txt to remote SSH which uses a password for login.

From OSX bash I use this command to send file manually:

```
scp /Users/myname/Documents/myfile.txt root@192.168.1.116:/Docs/myfile.txt
```

Since I need to do it via PHP, I made this `upload.sh` bash script:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
spawn scp /Users/myname/Documents/myfile.txt root@192.168.1.116:/Docs/myfile.txt
expect "root@192.168.1.116's password:"
send "mYpassWORD\r"
interact
```

I can run this above code with: `./update.sh` in terminal and it sends the file as I want.

Now problem is when I add this bash script in PHP, it dont send the file.

I have tried:

```
exec('/Library/WebServer/update.sh 2>&1', $output);
print_r($output);
```

And I am stuck at this error/msg:

```
Array
(
    [0] => spawn scp /Users/myname/Documents/myfile.txt root@192.168.1.116:/Docs/myfile.txt
    [1] => root@192.168.1.116's password:
)
```

In bash the password is sent and all is Ok, via PHP it dont uploads the file.
I also noticed first time I run it via PHP it said SSH Host Keys Dont match, so I copied .ssh folder to server root location and that error is gone.

Can anyone please help how to make it work?
Thank you

Comment: Have you tried to generate a pair of SSH keys and add your public key to the server's `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` file? This way you don't need to enter password, nor you need `expect`.

Comment: @RuslanOsmanov sorry, not sure. When I logged in via Terminal it asked if I want to save it in .ssh and I wrote yes. But when using PHP then Owner is WWW means different account? I copied my .ssh folder to server and now it doesn't ask for keys. I have not generated `authorized_keys`. I have only `known_hosts`. How can I do that? Thanks

Comment: You should not give your private keys to anyone(!). The handshake is done by means of the public keys. The trusted public keys are supposed to be registered in server's `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` file, and the public keys should be kept on the client's machine _only_. A pair of SSH keys can be generated with `ssh-keygen` utility. See [instructions on GitHub](https://help.github.com/articles/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent/), for example.

Comment: @RuslanOsmanov I generated Keys on local maskin and on remote also. But remote still asks for password. When accessing from local then I should use remote Public key or Private key? I tried both but no luck. I tried: `ssh -i id_rsa.txt root@192.168.1.116`

Comment: Generate a pair of keys on local machine. Put your public key into `$HOME/.ssh/authorized_keys` where `$HOME` is the home directory of `root`. Check if the SSH server configuration (`/etc/ssh/sshd_config`) matches your settings; `AuthorizedKeysFile` option is particularly important. You can use SSH client's `-v` option for debugging, e.g. `ssh -vvv root@...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Working as expected, but not a rocksolid solution.

I found a solution and got it working but not sure if this is the correct way.
The problem is not Password related. The problem is/was: The Bash script is too FAST. Or maybe PHP is too fast?

Anyway I solved my problem by adding `sleep` after `send "mYpassWORD\r"`.
Here is my working Bash command which I access from PHP to send file to remote with password:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
spawn scp /Library/WebServer/Documents/test34/myfile.txt root@192.168.1.116:/Docs/myfile.txt
expect "root@192.168.1.116's password:"
send "mYpassWORD\r"
sleep 0.2
interact
```

I saved this as: `update.sh` and did `chmod +x update.sh`

Then in PHP file: `index.php` i wrote:

```
<?php
$do = shell_exec("(/Library/WebServer/Documents/test34/update.sh)");
var_dump($do);
?>
```

And got this **SUCCESS result**:

```
string(320) "spawn scp /Library/WebServer/Documents/test34/myfile.txt root@192.168.1.116:/Docs/myfile.txt
root@192.168.1.116's password: 

myfile.txt                                  0%    0     0.0KB/s   --:-- ETA
myfile.txt                                100% 3649     3.6KB/s   00:00    
"
```

So just adding `sleep 0.2`in Bash script solved the problem.

I also tried `sleep 0.1` but then I got error. Therefore the sleep time might be depended on how big is your file? myfile.txt was only 3.6kb and 0.2 seconds sleep works great.

If your file is bigger you can try `sleep 1` or `sleep 5` etc..

This method works and solves the problem but doesn't feel secure since it might fail if file size varies on every call or if there is a slow ssh connection.

If anyone can contribute to improve this answer I will highly appreciate it.